Issues getting a Vetiver API to run
I'm trying to follow the docs for using Vetiver to get a ML model deployed to a cloud resource but I'm having issues running my Vetiver API.
I'm using the following code but when I run the server using pr_run(port = 8080) I don't get the full interactive endpoint that's discussed in the example described here
pacman::p_load(tidymodels, vetiver, googleCloudRunner, ranger, pins, plumber)

# Example data
data(iris)

# Split the data
set.seed(123)
split <- initial_split(iris, prop = 0.8)
train_data <- training(split)
test_data <- testing(split)

# Define the model
model_spec <- rand_forest() %>%
  set_mode("classification") %>%
  set_engine("ranger")

# Define the workflow
workflow <- workflow() %>%
  add_model(model_spec) %>%
  add_formula(Species ~ .)

# Train the model
rf_fit <- workflow %>%
  fit(data = train_data)

# Version the model
v <- vetiver_model(rf_fit, "iris_rf")

model_board <- board_temp()

model_board %>%
  vetiver_pin_write(v)

pr() %>%
  vetiver_api(v) %>% 
  pr_run(port = 8080)

I get the following window but there's option for interactivity. Any suggestions for resolving this would be greatly appreciated.


I'm not sure how possible it is to get an interactive API like this with googleCloudRunner. Instead, I would recommend creating the plumber file you need and then using the recommended method of deploying the plumber file via googleCloudRunner. Here are more details.
